# How to change the color tab when selecting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set the color of tab when I click on it. My code is :

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Tab-4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Tab-5</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-4">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-5">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="1"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to do it?

```
var value= "#ui-id-";
  var nithin = value +''+ $('#hidden').val();
   $(nithin).click(function () {
     $(nithin).css('background','red');
     var hidden=(parseInt('#hidden').val())+1;
     $('#hidden').val(hidden);
  });
```

Comment: So far what you have tried ?

Comment: Isn't this similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745959/change-color-of-selected-menu-tab?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Added css for a class called "selected" that sets the background color. Using jQuery, you can set up a click handler for your tabs, and when they are clicked, remove the "selected" class from all the tabs, and then add it to the one that was clicked, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(ev){
        $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('selected');
        $(ev.currentTarget).parent('li').addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

I created a fiddle to demonstrate this. I took the liberty of styling your tabs a little bit to make them look like tabs. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/d23Nk/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div#tabs ul li a').click(function() {

    $(this).parents('div#tabs').children('div').removeClass('activeColor');
    var theHref = $(this).attr('href');
    $('div#' + theHref).addClass('activeColor');

});
```

Then just define these CSS classes to have the colors you want

Comment: Did you add styles for .activeColor?  Like background-color: red

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
#tabs ul li { float:left }
#tabs div { display:none; clear:both }
#tabs div.selected { display:block }
```

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" class="selected">Tab-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab-3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="selected">tab 1 content</div>
      <div>tab 2 content</div>
      <div>tab 3 content</div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
            $('#tabs ul li, #tabs div').removeClass('selected');
            var x = $(this).parent().index();
            $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
            $('#tabs div:eq('+x+')').addClass('selected');
            return false;
    });
});
```

Doesn't require all the unique IDs, nor do you need to add classes before the javascript has time to interact with them.