# Change tab color in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I am trying to change the "look" of a tab when I select it.  I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240781/how-to-change-the-color-tab-when-selecting-it) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745959/change-color-of-selected-menu-tab?rq=1) but I am not sure I understand how to implement this.  To be simple, I am using this exact example posted on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NIkhar/NRkL9/2/).

This portion of code in my css does not seem to apply when I click on new tabs:

```
.tabContainer .digiTabs .selected {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #393939;
    border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-top: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-right: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    }
```

If you look at this example, change tabs, you will see that the tab content changes but not the look of the selected tab heading.  I can get my content to change, the only thing not changing is the tab color/background.

My current work is closely following this example so any help you can provide would be great!  Also, I am a noob to this stuff which is why I probably can't understand the answer from the other two SO questions.   Thanks!

Comment: because you never add the `selected` class to the clicked on tab, http://jsfiddle.net/NRkL9/51/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NRkL9/60/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use $(document).on() instead of .bind (which has been deprecated).

```
    $(document).on("click", ".t", function(){
        $(".tabContent").each(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#t"+id).show();
        $('.t').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

Comment: I changed my "bind" to document and combined that with Patrick Evans' code -- works perfectly!  Thanks